# A journey... into the MIND

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, mazes, nonogram

> [image: crossword]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Drench
>   6. Garland
>   7. Senior executive
>   8. Jack's fellow grumpy old man
>   9. Willy Wonka or the Mad Hatter
>   10. Chose between two pills
>   11. Iconic Dracula
>   12. Dissuade
>   13. West African nation
>
> **Down**
>   1. Sushi wrapping
>   2. Turned into violence-promising film
>   3. Perform on stage
>   4. Zoo official
>   5. Pathfinder's sinker
>   8. Darling in Neverland
>   9. Snooker champion
>   11. Feline in the night sky

The answer is a movie (mis?)quote.

Comment: Next puzzle awaits!! ;)

Comment: @user477343 Already under work :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> [image]

Answer is

> WE NEED TO GO DEEPER, which I believe is a (mis?)quotation from *Inception*.

(Note: I see that Weather Vane posted a partial while I was working on this, but obviously I didn't look at their answer.)

Comment: Ah, rot13(qvqa'g xabj vg jnf Vaprcgvba... gung rkcynvaf gur gvgyr, gbb)

Comment: Gareth I only got the easy bit anyway, and you just pipped Steve.

Comment: By 11 seconds! (Of course I have no way of telling which of us finished the crossword sooner.)

Comment: One wall piece is missing :) You still get the checkmark since you were the first to get the correct answer.

Comment: Oops, so it is! Sorry about that. In case it's not obvious, the missing piece is on a W.

Answer (score 14):

as Weathervane said, here is the crossword

> [image]

Then

> solving the outer numbers (yellow) gives a maze (blue)

Finally

> traversing the maze give "We need to go deeper"

Answer (score 10):

Step 1 - the crossword

> [image]

Step 2 - trying to figure out the other numbers and arrows.

> The numbers along the top sum to 17.
>  The numbers down the left sum to 17.
>  Are these coordinate pairs?
>
>  NO, because
>  the numbers on the left are not big enough to reach the right,
>  the numbers on the top are not big enough to reach the bottom.

Comment: The numbers along the top and bottom are a puzzle which I know as hanjie, but are apparently more commonly called [nonograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram)

Comment: @AndyT thanks - never done one.

Comment: Well now you've discovered them, say goodbye to the next few days of your life! ;) Have fun!